# How to Manage as a checkpoint on a game levels?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm creating a game at levels. At level 4 is obtained a checkpoint, which can be used only once after receiving it. Since I have a file for each level, which are a total of 7, how do I handle a variable that takes into account all the activity from the fourth to the seventh, if I have used or not the checkpoint. Bearing in mind that whenever start the intent of the activity level, i make a finish() on the start activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class `Player`? With member variables like `boolean hasReceivedCheckpoint` and `boolean hasCheckpointUsed`? If you have, you can pass an object of `Player` to the intent receiving Activity *and* pass back any changes that happen in the level-activity back to your "menu"-activity.